# Efficient way to pick/delete a list of rows/columns in a matrix in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

This question is in a way a continuation of the question I asked here:[Simple way to delete a matrix column in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289350/simple-way-to-delete-a-matrix-colum-in-mathematica) to which @belisarius and @Daniel provided very helpful answers.

What I am generally trying to do is to extract from a matrix A specific lines and columns OR what remains after what those specified are removed. So this can be formally writtewn as, find TakeOperator and Drop Operator such that:

TakeOperator[A,{i1,..,ip},{j1,...,jq}]=(A[[ik]][[jl]]) (1<=k<=p, 1<=l<=q) =`Table[A[[ik]][[jl]],{k,p},{l,q}]`

We note Ic={i'1,...,i'p'}=`Complement`[{1,...,`Length[A]`},{i1,...,ip}];Jc={j'1,...,j'q'}=`Complement`[{1,...,`Length[A]`},{j1,...,jq}];

DropOperator[A,{i1,..,ip},{j1,...,jq}]=(A[[ik]][[jl]]) (1<=k'<=p', 1<=l'<=q') =`Table[A[[ik']][[jl']],{k',p'},{l','q}]`

While `Table` as described above does the trick, it is highly inefficient to use Table in that manner.

Just to give an idea, I took @ belisarius example:

```
In: First@Timing[a = RandomInteger[1000, {5000, 5000}];]

Out:0.218

In:Clear[b,c]

In:First@Timing[
  b = Table[
    If[i < 100, If[j < 100, a[[i]][[j]], a[[i]][[j + 1]]], 
     If[j < 100, a[[i + 1]][[j]], a[[i + 1]][[j + 1]]]], {i, 
     4999}, {j, 4999}]]

Out:140.807

In:First@Timing[c = Drop[a, {100}, {100}]]

Out:0.093

In:c===b

Out:True
```

Note: With respect to the use of `Drop` in the earlier post, I thought about using it as well, but when I checked the documentation, there was no suggestion of getting it done the way @belisarius and @daniel suggested. If the documentation could be updated in that direction in future releases, it would be helpful.

Comment: You should check the **More information** section in the help. There is useful info there. In the **Drop** help entry you'll find   `{n} element n only` :D

Comment: @belisarius: yes. just saw it. it feels a little lost in the maze though...thanks.

Comment: That feeling is normal. It takes time to learn to navigate the help system and the inventory of functions is _huge_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Part` directly supports lists of indices when slicing arrays.  The following definitions exploit that:

```
takeOperator[a_?MatrixQ, rows_List, cols_List] :=
  a[[rows, cols]]

dropOperator[a_?MatrixQ, rows_List, cols_List] :=
 a[[##]]& @@ complementaryIndices[a, rows, cols]

complementaryIndices[a_?MatrixQ, rows_List, cols_List] :=
  Complement @@@ Transpose @ {Range /@ Dimensions @ a, {rows, cols}}
```

Example use:

```
a = RandomInteger[1000, {5000, 5000}];
First @ Timing @ takeOperator[a, Range[1, 5000, 2], Range[1, 5000, 2]]
(* 0.016 *)

First @ Timing @ dropOperator[a, Range[1, 5000, 2], Range[1, 5000, 2]]
(* 0.015 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use explicit ranges in a way that is fairly efficient. They may provide some more flexibility. Here is your example.

```
a = RandomInteger[1000, {5000, 5000}];

Timing[b = Drop[a, {101}, {101}];]
```

Out[66]= {0.041993, Null}

```
Timing[
  c = a[[Join[Range[100], Range[102, 5000]], 
   Join[Range[100], Range[102, 5000]]]];]
```

Out[67]= {0.061991, Null}

```
c == b
```

Out[62]= True

I would also suggest use of Span except offhand I do not see how to get it to work in this setting.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: @WReach: Thanks. To the point. I think it would be helpful if WRI could seamlessly integrate some choice support provided her in its software documentation illustrating the use of various functions of mathematica.